# How to empty TimePicker Field when entered first time

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

When showing `TimePicker` in Flutter how can I keep the hour and minute field empty so when user clicks the textfield that he can enter the time directly without removing 00 first.

[image]

```dart
final selectedTime = await showTimePicker(
  context: context,
  initialTime: const TimeOfDay(hour: 0, minute: 0),
  initialEntryMode: TimePickerEntryMode.input,
);
```